# How to access page views in Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-overview):

> "From the Usage blade, click through the Page Views tile to get a breakdown of your most popular pages:"

However there is no Page Views tile.  There is a request count chart and performance chart so I think it is configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just recently deployed an Application Insight service that might be why you're not seeing an option to view Page Views -- there is no usage yet.

I just configured one and I have no option for Page Views. This is what mine looks like:
[image]

You can also try adding it. From Overview -> select "Metrics Explorer" button in top bar -> "+ Add Chart" button -> in the slide out form, under "Usage" drop down you can select "Page Views".

Comment: Thank you tameikal, however my app has been running for months.

Comment: @Sam try adding it. From Overview -> select "Metrics Explorer" button in top bar -> "+ Add Chart" button -> in the slide out form, under "Usage" drop down you can select "Page Views"

Comment: Thank you! Please update your answer I will accept it.